# Why doesn't IntelliSense 'know' about my datatable?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datatable, intellisense

I created a dataset (DataSet1.xsd).  I then created a TableAdapter (DataTable1TableAdapter) and added a query (images below):

[image: dataset]

[image: query]

When I preview the data, I see exactly what I was expecting: lots of returned rows.

In my C# program, in the button1_Click event, I tried to type the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MailingList
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.DataTable1TableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet1.DataTable1);
            foreach (DataRow row in DataTable1.Rows)
            {
                // insert code here to work with the data
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that IntelliSense doesn't recognize my datatable and places a squiggly red line under it.  Since I described|desgined the datatable in the designer screen, shouldn't it be available to me to use in my program?  Or, do I have to define the datatable and add the columns to it within the program?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you add the Dataset to the form?

Comment: Ah, no, I did not.  My form has a button and a multi-line textbox.  I had intended to loop through the datatable and write out the results to the textbox.

Comment: Anurag, that was the solution.  I had to add the dataset, binding source, and tableAdapter to my form.  Only after this did the IntelliSense 'know' about my dataset/datatable.  If you put this as the answer, I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the [Dataset to Form1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/99tc57xa%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

From MSDN:

> Open the form or component you want to work with. If necessary, switch
>   to Design view of the designer. From the Data tab of the Toolbox, drag
>   a DataSet object onto the designer.
>
> The Choose a Dataset dialog box appears. Select Typed Dataset, and
>   then from the drop-down list, select the dataset you want to use, and
>   then click OK.
>
> The drop-down list is populated with a list of all typed dataset
>   classes in your project.

Comment: Thanks, Anurag!  This pointed me in the right direction.  I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

The DataTable is part of the DataSet and does not have a local reference.  Change

```
this.DataTable1TableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet1.DataTable1);
foreach (DataRow row in DataTable1.Rows)
```

to

```
this.DataTable1TableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet1.DataTable1);
foreach (DataRow row in this.DataSet1.DataTable1.Rows)
```

Comment: Thanks!  This worked, but only after I followed Anurag's suggestion that I needed to add the dataset (and binding source and table adapter) to my form.